# Regex match multiple groups

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following example of a string with regex which I am trying to match:

Regex:
`^\d{3}( [0-9a-fA-F]{2}){3}`

String to match:
`010 00 00 00`

My question is this - the regex matches and captures 1 group - the final `00` at the end of the string. However, I want it to match all three of the `00` groups at the end. Why doesn't this work? Surely the brackets should mean that they are all matched equally?

I know that I could just type out the three groups separately but this is just a short extract of a much longer string so that would be a pain. I was hoping that this would provide a more elegant solution but it seems my understanding is lacking somewhat!

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you have a quantifier on a capture group, you're only seeing the capture from the last iteration. Luckily for you though, .NET (unlike other implementations) provides a mechanism for retrieving captures from *all* iterations, via [the CaptureCollection class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.capturecollection.aspx). From the linked documentation:

> If a quantifier is applied to a capturing group, the CaptureCollection includes one Capture object for each captured substring, and the Group object provides information only about the last captured substring.

And the example provided from the linked documentation:

```
  // Match a sentence with a pattern that has a quantifier that  
  // applies to the entire group.
  pattern = @"(\b\w+\W{1,2})+";
  match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
  Console.WriteLine("Pattern: " + pattern);
  Console.WriteLine("Match: " + match.Value);
  Console.WriteLine("  Match.Captures: {0}", match.Captures.Count);
  for (int ctr = 0; ctr < match.Captures.Count; ctr++)
     Console.WriteLine("    {0}: '{1}'", ctr, match.Captures[ctr].Value);

  Console.WriteLine("  Match.Groups: {0}", match.Groups.Count);
  for (int groupCtr = 0; groupCtr < match.Groups.Count; groupCtr++)
  {
     Console.WriteLine("    Group {0}: '{1}'", groupCtr, match.Groups[groupCtr].Value);
     Console.WriteLine("    Group({0}).Captures: {1}", 
                       groupCtr, match.Groups[groupCtr].Captures.Count);
     for (int captureCtr = 0; captureCtr < match.Groups[groupCtr].Captures.Count; captureCtr++)
        Console.WriteLine("      Capture {0}: '{1}'", captureCtr, match.Groups[groupCtr].Captures[captureCtr].Value);
  }
```

Comment: Ah, ok.. I thought that the `{3}` would literally match the previous group in the same way 3 times. So this should fix me for .NET, but for other implementations is there a more elegant way than just repeating everything n times?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, I don't believe there is any other way.

Comment: Nice answer. I'd not twigged this one (though reading the help pages it did ring a bell).

Comment: Ok. I hadn't realised this. And unfortunately I don't think the behaviour above is really what I want. I will probably have to type if all out fully. Nevermind! Thanks a lot for your quick answer!

Answer (score 0):

This should work for your current string.  I'd need a better example (more strings etc.) to see if this would break for those.  The word boundary (\b) checks for any non-word character:

```
\b[0-9a-fA-F]{2}\b
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me.. I assume you meant to expand to `(\b[0-9a-fA-F]{2}\b){3}`?

Comment: I believe I misinterpreted your question, acheong looks like he has the right idea