# REGEX matcher any/all groups

Tags: java, regex

```
while (matcher.find()) {
    if (matcher.group(matcherGroup) != null) occurrence++;
}
return occurrence;
```

This is the code that i am using to search for the number of matches of a certain group. However there is no function like `matcher.group(matcherGroup1, matcherGroup2)` nor there is `matcher.group(null)` to search for multiple groups or all groups.

I have read  [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13689259/regex-match-multiple-groups) groups (its stupid to group the arrays into one) or multiple groups?

Thanks

Comment: What is your final goal? Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not write your own matcherGroup implementation?  The link you have provided is c#.

I have written a simple Java implementation which takes a single string, and then matches it against multiple RegExp patterns.  The number of matches are then returned.

Alternatively please explain in more detail what you are trying to do.

```
package com.chocksaway;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class SingleMatcher {
    private Pattern pattern;
    private java.util.regex.Matcher matcher;
    private boolean found;

    SingleMatcher(String input, String inputPattern) {
        pattern = Pattern.compile(inputPattern);
        matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

        if (matcher.find()) {
            this.found = true;
        }
    }

    boolean getFound() {
        return this.found;
    }
}

class MatcherGroup {
    private int matchedOccurances;

    MatcherGroup(String input, List<String> multipleInputPattern) {
        for (String inputPattern : multipleInputPattern) {
            SingleMatcher eachSingleMatcher = new SingleMatcher(input, inputPattern);
            if (eachSingleMatcher.getFound()) {
                matchedOccurances++;
            }
        }
    }

    int getMatchedOccurances() {
        return this.matchedOccurances;
    }
}

/**
* Author milesd on 28/05/2017.
*/
public class RegExpMatcher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SingleMatcher singleMatcher = new SingleMatcher("123", "\\d\\d\\d");
        System.out.println(singleMatcher.getFound());

        List<String> inputPatternList = new ArrayList<String>();
        inputPatternList.add("\\d\\d\\d");
        inputPatternList.add("John");

        MatcherGroup matcherGroup = new MatcherGroup("John", inputPatternList);
        System.out.println(matcherGroup.getMatchedOccurances());

    }
}
```