# Regex Expression match value gives false, whats wrong with expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have below kind of string,

*<155>33739: 033910: *Dec 12 01:09:12.669 UTC: **%test1-3-test2**: Hello, How era you*

Here,

1. I have 6 colon (:)
2. Have a special set of strings, 
   **%**(1 or more char or num)**-**(one num)**-**(1 or more char or num)

Below regex expression match gave result as *false*, whats need to change in regex expression. Thanks!

```
private static bool IsValid(string value)
    {
        const string expression = @"(\w+):(\w+):(\w+):%(\w+)-(\d)(\w+):(\w+)";

        return Regex.IsMatch(value, expression, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    }

var X = IsValid("<155>33739: 033910: *Dec 12 01:09:12.669 UTC: %XYz-3-UPDxyt: Hello, How era you");
```

Comment: You have **6 colons (:)**

Comment: Yes, sorry. I overlooked date/time

Comment: You can also (in .NET only) _quantify a match group_, like so [(?:(.+?)(?::\s|$))+](https://regex101.com/r/A8Usal/3/) - this will match anything up to space-colon or EOL, as many times as it'll match - you won't see it on Regexr but that will remember every group in .NET, not just the last one.  After running the match access  the `Captures` instead of `Groups`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13689259/regex-match-multiple-groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression is missing the white spaces after the colons, the initial `<` and `>` and also special chars like the '*' which is (if I remember correctly) not covered by `\w`. Try this one:

Input:
`<155>33739: 033910: *Dec 12 01:09:12.669 UTC: %XYz-3-UPDxyt: Hello, How era you`

Regex:
`<(\d+)>(\d+):\s+(\d+):\s+([^%]+)%([A-Za-z]+)-(\d+)-([A-Za-z]+):\s+([\w,\s]+)`

Matches:

```
#0 '<155>33739: 033910: *Dec 12 01:09:12.669 UTC: %XYz-3-UPDxyt: Hello, How era you'
#1 '155'
#2 '33739'
#3 '033910'
#4 '*Dec 12 01:09:12.669 UTC: '
#5 'XYz'
#6 '3'
#7 'UPDxyt'
#8 'Hello, How era you'
```

C# Code v1, indexed groups:

```
var input = @"<155>33739: 033910: *Dec 12 01:09:12.669 UTC: %XYz-3-UPDxyt: Hello, How era you";
var regex = new Regex(@"<(\d+)>(\d+):\s+(\d+):\s+([^%]+)%([A-Za-z]+)-(\d+)-([A-Za-z]+):\s+([\w,\s]+)");
var match = regex.Match(input);
if (match.Success)
{
    var date = match.Groups[4];
}
```

C# Code v2, named groups, put `?<yourname>` in the group:

```
var input = @"<155>33739: 033910: *Dec 12 01:09:12.669 UTC: %XYz-3-UPDxyt: Hello, How era you";
var regex = new Regex(@"<(\d+)>(\d+):\s+(\d+):\s+(?<date>[^%]+)%([A-Za-z]+)-(\d+)-([A-Za-z]+):\s+([\w,\s]+)");
var match = regex.Match(input);
if (match.Success)
{
    var date = match.Groups["date"];
}
```

*Seems like named groups are moved to the end of the matching groups. So either name them all or don't name them...*

Comment: Thanks Michael. Is there any way to split the string like you show in your answer #1, #2,....etc.

Comment: it's already split up that way by virtue of your (and Michael's) parenthetical match groups, you just need to access them after running `Match` or `Matches` (not `isMatch`)

Comment: Thanks much @sweaver.